# Fixing angular installation 15.0.5

Tags: node.js, angular

`ng v` shows:

```
Angular CLI: 15.0.5
Node: 16.15.1
Package Manager: npm 9.2.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: <error>
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1500.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.1.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core            15.0.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.0.5 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    15.0.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             15.0.5 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.6.7 (cli-only)
typescript                      4.9.4 (cli-only)
```

How do I resolve the part which shows `Angular: <error>`?

I have tried:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm i -g @angular/cli@15.0.5
```

But I get the same result.

Comment: This is what I would expect, since all you have installed is the CLI. What happens when you tri `ng new my-app`? This also presumes that you have satisfied the requirements found at https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Answer (score 0):

in your case you should approve the version of the typescript.
I suppose, you have to upgrade your typescript version!

Comment: Why? I'm not getting a typescript error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @MattW I mean, Angular CLI is also checking the typescript version and throughs a warning like you have if there are some incompatibilities. I may be wrong, but that is what I would do first.